# Pandas dropna not working as expected

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe and I used dropna() on it successfully as shown:

```
proc_train.isnull().any()

id                                  False
perc_premium_paid_by_cash_credit    False
age_in_days                         False
Income                              False
Count_3-6_months_late               False
Count_6-12_months_late              False
Count_more_than_12_months_late      False
application_underwriting_score      False
no_of_premiums_paid                 False
premium                             False
renewal                             False
sourcing_channel_B                  False
sourcing_channel_C                  False
sourcing_channel_D                  False
sourcing_channel_E                  False
Urban/Rural                         False
prem_to_inc_ratio                   False
late36_612                          False
late36_12more                       False
late612_12more                      False
perc_times_prem                     False
```

Then I try to take a selection of the data to use as input variables:

```
X_train = proc_train.loc[:, proc_train.columns != 'renewal']
X_train = X.loc[:, X.columns != 'id']
```

but it then gives all the null values back:

```
X_train.isnull().any()

perc_premium_paid_by_cash_credit    False
age_in_days                         False
Income                              False
Count_3-6_months_late                True
Count_6-12_months_late               True
Count_more_than_12_months_late       True
application_underwriting_score       True
no_of_premiums_paid                 False
premium                             False
sourcing_channel_B                  False
sourcing_channel_C                  False
sourcing_channel_D                  False
sourcing_channel_E                  False
Urban/Rural                         False
prem_to_inc_ratio                   False
late36_612                           True
late36_12more                        True
late612_12more                       True
perc_times_prem                     False
```

Why does this happen and what would be a better way to run this?

Comment: Your output only proves that X_train, which comes from _X_ (whatever that is) has some null values.   That proc_train, at one point, didn't have any, doesn't seem relevant.  Please construct a [mcve].

Comment: Oh I see, that was a mistake. Now I know why it wasn't working...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This section:

```
X_train = X.loc[:, X.columns != 'id']
```

should be

```
X_train = X_train.loc[:, X_train.columns != 'id']
```

which produces the same all-False result for isnull().any() as before.